# Is using the shutdown command to turn off the system safe?

Tags: command-line, power-management, shutdown

I have seen many articles and posts stating that a way to turn off the system via the terminal is issuing the `shutdown -h now` command. It obviously works on my system, but it shuts down everything extremely fast. If I power off the system using Ubuntu's GUI, the Ubuntu splash screen comes up, and it takes much more time before it actually powers down. By *safe* I am referring to a shutdown that makes sure all read/write operations are completed before powering down and avoiding data corruption.

So is using the `shutdown` command in the terminal actually a safe way to power off the system? If so, why does Ubuntu's shutdown menu take much longer to accomplish the same goal?

Comment: Take a look at [Understanding Shutdown, Poweroff, Halt and Reboot Commands in Linux](https://www.tecmint.com/shutdown-poweroff-halt-and-reboot-commands-in-linux/)

Comment: @guillermochamorro They go over the `-H` (halt) option, but do not seem to go over the `-h` option which is supposedly equivalent to `--poweroff` according to the man page. Plus it doesn't seem like a good source of information considering they talk about `shutdown -p` which is not even a real option. They probably meant `shutdown -P`.

Comment: My *guess* would be that the GUI shutdown command is a little slow for the same reason that most GUI commands are a little slow - they attempt to make nice pretty screens, and give you time to look at them.  I boot without the splash screen, and I generally shutdown from the command line - the command I see scrolling past on the screen indicate that filesystems are being sync'd and unmounted - processes are closing in an orderly manner...  I'm not sure what more you would want.

Comment: @CharlesGreen "I'm not sure what more you would want" Lol I don't want anything more and never implied I did. I don't see anything scrolling by on the screen when I use the shutdown command, so I wouldn't be able to tell it is stopping read and write operations, unmounting filesystems, etc etc.

Answer (score 2):

### YES it is safe but...

Shutdown does more than simply flush unwritten data from RAM to disk. In some installations it can be setup to run custom jobs:

- [Execute a script upon logout/reboot/shutdown in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293312/execute-a-script-upon-logout-reboot-shutdown-in-ubuntu)

But as an answer here points out:

- [Difference between shutdown options](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1127222/difference-between-shutdown-options)

The shutdown `halt` option (designated by `shutdown -h` in your question) does flush all the buffers and safely unmount the disks but it doesn't actually turn off the machine. To do that use:

```
poweroff
```

> `halt` means flush buffers, unmount drives, close all processes in a
>   graceful way. But not power off (though some systems may power off
>   anyway). So the hardware is still provided with power.
>
> After halt a hard power off (pressing the power button or unplugging
>   the power supply) will not damage the system, because it is already
>   halted in a graceful way.

Comment: So it's recommended to run the following sequence? `shutdown -h; poweroff`
Maybe a custom script makes sense here too eh?

Comment: @sayandcode `poweroff` shuts down the system: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-shutdown-linux/